# Flutter - programmatically update TextField to show scrolling info

Tags: flutter

I'd like to show some debug info in my App (e. g. user pressed Button A) and was thinking of using the TextField widget for this.

Using below code, I can record ambient sound from my phone and I'd like to add a widget at the bottom that displays timestamps of when the recordings started and stopped, including length of the recording. The idea is to use a ring buffer (package:circular_buffer) that keeps track of a pre-defined number of text lines being displayed in the TextField. Whenever something happens, the new debug info is added as an element to the ring buffer and the TextField is updated. I am very new to flutter, so I'm completely unsure how to achieve this. I was trying to use setState() but I don't know how to call it from other widgets. Is there a way to register as listener to state changes of other widgets and update the text accordingly?

```
import 'dart:async';
import 'dart:io';

// locale, datetime formatting
import 'package:intl/intl.dart';

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:record/record.dart';
import 'package:path_provider/path_provider.dart';

// local imports
import './display_timer.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(myApp());
}

class myApp extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  myAppState createState() => myAppState();
}

class myAppState extends State<myApp> {
  final record = Record();
  bool bPressed = false;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
        title: 'Record',
        home: Scaffold(
          appBar: AppBar(
            title: const Text('Record'),
          ),
          body: Center(
            child:
                Column(mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center, children: [
              ElevatedButton(
                child: bPressed ? const Text("Stop") : const Text("Record"),
                onPressed: () {
                  setState(() {
                    bPressed = !bPressed;
                  });
                  action();
                },
              ),
              if (bPressed)
                ElapsedTime(timestamp: DateTime.now().toString())
              else
                const Text("")
            ]),
          ),
        ));
  }

  String getTimestampSec() {
    DateTime now = DateTime.now();
    var dateString = DateFormat('yyyyMMdd_hhmmss').format(now);

    return dateString;
  }

  Future<void> action() async {
    // Get the state of the recorder
    bool isRecording = await record.isRecording();

    // Check and request permission
    if (await record.hasPermission()) {
      if (isRecording) {
        // Stop recording
        await record.stop();
      } else {
        // get write dir
        // TODO: add fnc so dir only has to be initialize once
        Directory appDocDir = await getApplicationDocumentsDirectory();
        String appDocPath = appDocDir.path;
        String outFile =
            "$appDocPath/${getTimestampSec()}_ambient_test.m4a";
        print("saving audio to: $outFile");

        // Start recording
        await record.start(
          path: outFile,
          encoder: AudioEncoder.aacLc, // by default
          bitRate: 128000, // by default
          samplingRate: 44100, // by default
        );
      }
    }

    print('Pressed');
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To use `setState()` every time is not good practice rather than you can use `ValueNotifier`. Every time you update the string value it notify to your TextField and it will update TextField data.

```
ValueNotifier<String> logText = ValueNotifier<String>("Welcome");


 ValueListenableBuilder(
     valueListenable: logText,
     builder: (context, logTextUpdate,child) {
            return Text(
                 "${logText.value}",
                 style: TextStyle(fontSize: 25),
            );
}),
```

when you want to update your text, assign value to logText

```
logText.value = "Happy to see you!"
```

Comment: Thank you for the interesting suggestion. I'll try it out. An alternative I found is to expose the TextEditingController of the TextField so its text property can be updated from the outside.